# Generate JWT token on successful authentication with Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt

I'm having some difficulty understanding how to use Windows Authentication to authenticate a user, but then return a JWT to the client containing that authenticated user's claims. This is using .Net Core 2.0.

I've put the following in Startup.cs.

```
services.AddAuthentication
  (
     IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
  ).AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
  {
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateAudience = false,
      ValidateIssuer = false,

      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someKey")),

      ValidateLifetime = true,
    };
  }
);
```

However, it doesn't seem that this is sufficient to generate the token. Some other guidance I've read suggests the token should be generate manually as part of an authorization routine but this seems to be tailored for when validating a username/password against a database or other provider. (For instance: https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login.) But with windows auth there does not appear to be an event or other structure that allows me to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to answer this @christok? I have a very similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711147/use-windows-auth-to-authenticate-user-and-then-generate-jwt-in-aspnet-core-2-1

Comment: @christok yes, you have to generate a JWT-Token manually on the basis of an authenticated windows user - JWT middleware just evaluates tokens.