# Use Windows Auth to authenticate user and then generate JWT in ASPNET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebApi, in which I have implemented JWT authentication. The user calls `api/authentication/authenticate`, passes their username/password in the message body, and gets back a JWT in return which they then use to access the service.

I also need the API to accept Windows authentication -- the user will call `api/authentication/windows` passing no user information, the service will check they are in the list of authorized users as listed in the web.config file (if I am hosting in IIS). If so, return a JWT token and the user can use that to access the service.

Currently I'm thinking about this...

1. The `api/authentication/windows` method will get the username from the request
2. Check the username against the list of authorized users. If they are on it, return a token. If not, go to (3)
3. Check against any groups in the authorized users list. If they are a member, return a token. If not, return a 401 Unauthorized error

Is this the correct way to approach this?

Very similar (unanswered) question here: [Generate JWT token on successful authentication with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045940/generate-jwt-token-on-successful-authentication-with-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable both JWT and AD authentication ,in my option, you still need to validate the user's credential(username/password) against  Active Directory in web api :

https://www.brechtbaekelandt.net/blog/post/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-aspnet-core-2-and-managing-users

Pass just username won't work since there is no authenticated user context in web api .

After validating user credential  , you can generate jwt token as usual , for example if using HS256:

```
private string BuildToken()
{
    var claims = new[] {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId,"name1"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,"name1"),
        new Claim("customer","customer1"),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,"wuxiyuan@sina,com"),
        new Claim("role","user"),
    };

    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Youkey"));
    var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken("name1",
        "name1",
    claims,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    signingCredentials: creds);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

Comment: That's not correct. You can use attribute to specify what your each Web API endpoint use as authentication. 

For windows:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

For JWT: 
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

Answer (score 0):

- To get the username from the request to the route `api/authentication/windows` you should activate [windows authentication for the asp.net core application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). You can achieve that either modifying the web.config or enable the [windows authentication in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/).

```
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <security>
         <authentication>
           <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
           <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
         </authentication>
       </security>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```

- For [debugging purposes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#launch-settings-debugger) modify `launchSettings.json`:

```
   "iisSettings": {
     "windowsAuthentication": true,
   }
```

- Leave the anonymous authentication activated: `<anonymousAuthentication enabled="`**true**`" />`. It is necessary in order the JWT authentication works properly for the route `api/authentication/authenticate`
- Make sure that the attribute `forwardWindowsAuthToken` of the aspNetCore element in `web.config` is not deactivated: `forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"` or remove it because of the default value (*true*)
- Add [IISIntegration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#out-of-process-hosting-model) to the webHostBuilder unless you use a default builder: `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` - [UseIISIntegration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderiisextensions.useiisintegration?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is called implicit within this extension method.
- Add an [Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) attribute for the `POST`-method which will be mapped with the route `api/authentication/windows`
- Test the authentication (sending windows-credentials):

```
    var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    };

    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost")
    };

    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("api/authentication/windows", null);
```

or using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/api/authentication/windows', true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send();
```

- Get the user name in the controller:

```
    var username = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
```

- Generate a JWT-Token, e.g using [jose-jwt](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt):

```
 var claims = new Dictionary<string, object>
 {
     ["jti"] = Guid.NewGuid(),
     ["sub"] = username,
     ["exp"] = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(100).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
 };

 var secretKey = new byte[] { 164, 60, 194, 0, 161 };

 var headers = new Dictionary<string, object>
 {
     ["alg"] = "HS512",
     ["typ"] = "JWT"
 };

 var token = JWT.Encode(claims, secretKey, JwsAlgorithm.HS512, headers);
```